# OpenCV : Working with PGM file. Why my generated PGM file has 3 channels (RGB)?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to generate PGM file with OpenCV, this is how I do it :

```
ori = imread("images/apple.jpg");
cvtColor(ori, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); //convert to gray    

vector<int> params;
params.push_back(IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY);
params.push_back(1); 

imwrite("images/apple1.pgm", gray, params); //because it needs gray input
pgm = imread("images/apple1.pgm");
imshow("PGM", pgm);
```

I could generate PGM file successfully and display it using `imshow`. However I noticed that my PGM file has 3 channels (RGB), which was unexpected since it's supposed to have just 1 channel per pixel.

I loaded the same file into GIMP and exported it into PGM format. When I tried to show it on OpenCV using `imshow` as well, it displayed the right channel (1 channel) comparison from GIMP and PGM from my code is below :

[image]

Notice at bottom left of each image, number of channel. I tried to convert it into single channel with this :

```
pgm.convertTo(pgm, CV_8U);
```

But my PGM image still consist of 3 channels. Any advice which part I'm missing from my PGM conversion ?

Comment: imread by default read 3 channels (if the image was grayscale, it converts it to 3 channels). use `imread(..., cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`

Comment: @Miki Hi, thanks! It worked. Could you please put your answer in the answer section ? So I can accept it as the answer ? Actually, I also just realized, despite using the same source, those 2 pictures look different.

Comment: You can post the answer ;)